# How to fix the error Failed to add a SAML/WS-Fed identity provider?

Tags: azure, authentication, single-sign-on, saml, federation

I am working on edit a SAML/WS-Fed IdP federation relationship on Microsoft azure portal.

After login to the azure portal went to external identities menu and click on add new identity provider option. There click on add New SAML/WS-Fed IDP.

Then the new form open & attached the federation XML but when clicked on save button getting the failed to add a SAML/WS-Fed identity provider error.
[form shows error on submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC3mJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I get the metadata file as an XML document on my PC.

Then "Parse metadata file".

Then I browse to the XML file from that blade and click "Parse".

It then fills out the fields automatically and you can click "Save".